# Insert and select in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, select, insert

I have very strange problem.

After a lot of debugging I come to following line of code:

```
db.db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO goal_calendar(timestamp) VALUES(1)", null);
db.cursor = db.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM goal_calendar", null);
Log.e("SIZE", String.valueOf(db.cursor.getCount()));
```

The result is "Size 0".
There is no any errors at all. Everything worked just fine and suddenly it didn't want to store nothing in my table. It just stopped. What could be wrong?

According to me the result after these three lines of code SHOULD ALWAYS be error(exception) or SIZE should be greater than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this

```
"INSERT INTO goal_calendar(timestamp) VALUES(1)"
```

**is not a QUERY** (SELECT),but a **COMMAND**.

For commands (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ...), use this:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO goal_calendar (timestamp) VALUES (1)", null);
```

I also have some doubts on why do you **double "db."**
I'd use "db.rawQuery" and "db.execSQL", instead of "db.db.rawQuery" and "db.db.execSQL".

Now two words of explanation:
Your INSERT statement doesn't work. That's why your query correctly returns a zero count.

Comment: Thx a lot. I thought that rawQuery could be used for everything, but I was wrong :)

Comment: It happens, when you're fresh to databases, to confuse queries and commands.